# How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?

Tags: java, android

I've 16 textViews and need to set something like this done:

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++)
{
    int $RidInt = R.id.s; 
    tv[i] = (TextView)findViewById($RidInt);
    tv[i].setTypeface(face);
    tv[i].setClickable(true);
    tv[i].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

my R.java file is :

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int s1=0x7f050000;
        public static final int s10=0x7f050009;
        public static final int s11=0x7f05000a;
        public static final int s12=0x7f05000b;
        public static final int s13=0x7f05000c;
        public static final int s14=0x7f05000d;
        public static final int s15=0x7f05000e;
        public static final int s16=0x7f05000f;
        public static final int s2=0x7f050001;
        public static final int s3=0x7f050002;
        public static final int s4=0x7f050003;
        public static final int s5=0x7f050004;
        public static final int s6=0x7f050005;
        public static final int s7=0x7f050006;
        public static final int s8=0x7f050007;
        public static final int s9=0x7f050008;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
        public static final int toast=0x7f030001;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
        public static final int s2=0x7f040001;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like that?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
/* ... */

for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    int id = R.id.class.getField("s" + i).getInt(0);
    tv[i] = (TextView)findViewById(id);
    tv[i].setTypeface(face);
    tv[i].setClickable(true);
    tv[i].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

Comment: for some reason I need to add a try/catch block - but works beautifully! anyway to avoid the try/catch?

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
            for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ((TextView) ll.getChildAt(i)).setText("Text View " + i);
            }
```

Comment: I think this will throw a lot of CastingExpcetions if not all childs are textviews

Comment: mgpyone asked "I've 16 textViews and need to set something like this done:". you can place all textviews in one linear layout.
and i am just giving a hint that this is also a way to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I had to wrap mine in a try/catch wrapper, not sure why, but I'm Very New.

```
for (int counter = 1; player < 5; counter++) {
        try {Field field = example.main.R.id.class.getField("s" + counter);
             try {screenid = field.getInt(null);} 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e){//exceptioncodehere}
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {//exception2codehere}
        TextView SetMe = (TextView)findViewById(screenid);
        SetMe.setText("Text" + player);}}
```