# Retrieve Group of Buttons in Main.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I created nine `Butto`n view in the `main.xml` and named it to `Button1, Button2... Button9..` Then in my code I created an `ArrayList` of Button and its obvious that this array of buttons will hold my Button in the `main.xml` and in my current knowledge that to get the Button in my main.xml I need to use the findViewById method and basically I need to loop the array to get the button

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons;
int MAXBTN = 9;
for( int i = 0; i < BTN; i++ )
{
    // Code here to use the findViewById method to get the button
}
```

And my problem is that I need to pass `R.id.Button1 .. R.id.Button3` to the findViewById method, but I need to loop this. Is there anyway I can pass a counter in the `findViewById` while loop?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons;
int MAXBTN = 9;
for( int i = 0; i < BTN; i++ )
{
    String buttonID = "Button" + i+1 ;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", "packageName");
    buttons.get(i) = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
}
```

Comment: Your package name(find at the top area of your java file).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is already a same question asked for this [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class)

---

Its always better to search first before asking

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that next time.