# How to reference R.id s with indices?

Tags: android, for-loop, android-edittext

I've got this in my activity.java file.

```
    text[0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    text[1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text[2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    text[3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    text[4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    text[5] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    text[6] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    text[7] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
```

How can I write it with a for loop.

```
 for(int i=o;i<8;i++)
 text[i] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.<what here>);
```

**How to reference edittext with index here?**

Comment: Don't think you can do it directly, but just put the necessary ids to an array and loop over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `getIdentifier()`

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
    String editTextID = "btn" + i + "-" + j;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(editTextID
    ,"id", "com.example.yourpackagename");
    buttons[i][j] = ((EditTextID) findViewById(resID));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant array for this.

```
// in your class 
private static final int[] TEXT_IDS = { R.id.editText2, R.id.editText3, ... , R.id.editText9};

//initializing
for(int i = o; i < TEXT_IDS.length; i++)
    text[i] = (EditText) findViewById(TEXT_IDS[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the answer below, which is taken verbatim from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941538/826731).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
/* ... */

for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    int id = R.id.class.getField("s" + i).getInt(0);
    tv[i] = (TextView)findViewById(id);
    tv[i].setTypeface(face);
    tv[i].setClickable(true);
    tv[i].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```