# Enable iterate through R file in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to iterate through all `R.id` to find all `ImageView` objects and change there properties. but Android studio gives me an error.

here is code

```
public void initializeChipsViewholdersArray (){
   for (int i = 1; i<10; i ++){
        String viewholderName = "chip_00"+i;
       int id_2 = R.id.class.getFields(viewholderName).getInt(0);//erorr here
   ImageView chipViewholder= (ImageView)findViewById(id);
           chipViewholder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

here is error

> Error:(28, 33) error: method getFields in class Class cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: no arguments
>   found: String
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends Object declared in class Class

The solution I choose has been discussed here [How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class)

Comment: Class.getFields() doesn't take an argument.  Did you mean getField().get(null)?

Comment: `getFields()` return all the public fields inside the `R.id` class, which is a static inner class inside the `R` class, which is a Java auto generated class for Resources. That method, `getFields()`, doesn't take any argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFields()` return all the public fields inside the `R.id` class, which is a static inner class inside the `R` class, which is a Java auto generated class for Resources. That method, `getFields()`, doesn't take any argument

You are looking for `getField()`, not `getFields()`

```
public void initializeChipsViewholdersArray (){
   for (int i = 1; i<10; i ++){
        String viewholderName = "chip_00"+i;
       int id_2 = R.id.class.getField(viewholderName).getInt(0);
   ImageView chipViewholder= (ImageView)findViewById(id);
           chipViewholder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```